Prove one specific Upper bound of the minimum time of a p-processor schedule
In spring18 mcs.pdf, it has Problem 10.26:

We want to schedule n tasks with prerequisite constraints among the tasks defined
by a DAG.
(a) Explain why any schedule that requires only p processors must take time at
least $\lceil n/p\rceil$.
(b) Let $D_{n,t}$ be the DAG with n elements that consists of a chain of $t-1$ elements,
with the bottom element in the chain being a prerequisite of all the remaining ele-
ments as in the following figure:
What is the minimum time schedule for $D_{n,t}$ ? Explain why it is unique. How many
processors does it require?
(c) Write a simple formula $M(n,t,p)$ for the minimum time of a p-processor
schedule to complete $D_{n,t}$ .
(d) Show that every partial order with n vertices and maximum chain size t has a
p-processor schedule that runs in time $M(n,t,p)$.
Hint: Use induction on t.


The processor means CPU core. The above (b) is about concurrency.

They capture key con-
cepts used in analyzing task scheduling and concurrency control. When distributing
a program across multiple processors, we’re in trouble if one part of the program
needs an output that another part hasn’t generated yet!

I can understand (a,b).
For (b), since we must do $n-(t-1)$ bottom tasks first if possible with $n-(t-1)$ number of processors
and then follow the chain of $t-1$ tasks which is the minimal steps to do due to dependency.
Since each step is determined, it is unique.
For (c) I have answer $M(n,t,p)=\lceil \frac{n-(t-1)}{p}\rceil+t-1$ which includes the case $M(n,t,p)=t,p\ge n-(t-1)$.
For (d), it only cares about one upper bound of the scheduling since the scheduling for one  general DAG is NP-Complete.
Assume at the bottom depth, it has $k\ge 1$ elements. Then by (a) we have at most $\lceil \frac{k}{p}\rceil$ time to finish these elements. By induction, we need at most $\lceil \frac{n-k-(t-2)}{p}\rceil+t-2$. Then we need to prove $$\lceil \frac{k}{p}\rceil+\lceil \frac{n-k-(t-2)}{p}\rceil+t-2\le \lceil \frac{n-(t-1)}{p}\rceil+t-1.$$ This means $f(k)=\lceil \frac{k}{p}\rceil+\lceil \frac{m-k}{p}\rceil,1\le k\le m-1$ achieves its maximum when $k=1$.
By intuitive understanding, $\lceil \frac{1}{p}\rceil$ rounds too much to 1. So when $k$ increases, $\lceil \frac{1}{p}\rceil$ may remain while $\lceil \frac{m-k}{p}\rceil$ will decrease by 1 at some time. This implies the above inequality is probably true.
Q:
Can we interpret (d) as the above proposition about $f(k)$? If so, then how to prove that?

Your link is not to the pdf.  And it is immediately unclear what a "processor" is: in particular, "How many processors does it require?" relative to what requirement?

@JulioDiEgidio 1. Thanks for your notice. 2. I updated my question post. Hope the ambiguity goes away.
